# changing date format in R from one column to two

Tags: r, date, multiple-columns

I have a data frame and in the first column I have the date as month/day/year. Is there a way that I can take this format and change it so I have two columns representing the dates?  The format I need it for the first column to be the numerical day of the year and the second column to be the time.  For example the first day will have in the first column 48 1's and in the second column the times starting with 0000 to 2330. Then on day two the times will start over at 0000.  Below is a brief example of how it should be

```
DAY    TIME
1      2200
1      2230
1      2300
1      2330
2      0000
2      0030
```

I need this for the entire year.  I have found functions to change the format of the date but I don't know how to separate it into two columns like this.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your current data?

Comment: If you want time as an output you need a datetime variable and not just month/day/year data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `day` `hour` and `minute` functions of the `lubridate` package do the job.

```
require(lubridate)
day <- day(Sys.time())
#16
time <- paste0(hour(Sys.time()),minute(Sys.time()))
#"2056"
```

Comment: I didn't use exactly this but I was able to work out what I needed with the lubridate package.  Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
strftime(strptime(day, '%m/%d/%Y'), "%j")
strftime(day, "%H%M")
```